# Python Tkinter Scrollbar panning upwards instead of downwards also alignment issue while using Scrollbar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview, scrollbar

I am using TKinter to build a GUI for my python application.

I want to add a scrollbar to the main screen because I have a lot of data to display but very less space.
Currently I use the lines:

```
root=Tk()
root.state("zoomed")
#...rest of the code... (Relevant parts mentioned below:)
root.mainloop()
```

to take maximum advantage of available screen space but even that is not cutting it for me.

Here is John Elder(CEO of Codemy.com)'s [code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WafQCaok6g&ab_channel=Codemy.com) that I use to add a scrollbar:

```
# Create A Main Frame
    main_frame = Frame(root)
    main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    # Create A Canvas
    my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    # Add A Scrollbar To The Canvas
    my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
    my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

    # Configure The Canvas
    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
    def _on_mouse_wheel(event):
        my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int((event.delta / 100)), "units")

    my_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mouse_wheel)

    # Create ANOTHER Frame INSIDE the Canvas
    encompasser = Frame(my_canvas, bg=mainbg)

    # Add that New frame To a Window In The Canvas
    my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=encompasser, anchor="n")

    #Adding the scroll bar part ends here...

    encompasser=Frame(my_canvas,bg=mainbg, borderwidth=0)
    encompasser.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    #second_frame = LabelFrame(my_canvas, borderwidth=0, bg=mainbg).pack()
    header=LabelFrame(encompasser,bg=mainbg, borderwidth=0)
    header.pack()
    greet=Label(header,font="Arial 20",text="Prescription Generator V4.0.0", bg=mainbg, fg="black").pack(pady=10)

    utilitiesF=LabelFrame(header,bg=mainbg, borderwidth=0)
    utilitiesF.pack()

    settingLF=LabelFrame(utilitiesF,bg=mainbg, borderwidth=0)

    megaF=LabelFrame(encompasser,bg=mainbg, borderwidth=0)
    megaF.pack()

    dateF=LabelFrame(utilitiesF, padx=10, pady=10, bg=mainbg, borderwidth=0)
    dateF.grid(row=0, column=1)

    date=Label(dateF,font="Arial 14",text="Date:", bg=mainbg).grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=E)
    edate=Entry(dateF, width=9,borderwidth=0, font="Arial 14")
    edate.insert(0,today)
    edate.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

    my_tree_frame=LabelFrame(header, padx=10, pady=10, bg=subbg, borderwidth=0)
    my_tree_frame.pack()
```

[Dormant scrollbar added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvFm6.png)

After Adding the scroll bar to the canvas and opening the canvas in a frame, I add things to the frame called "encompasser".

Problem: when I click on the button: **Show Database**, The following Treeview opens up:
[Treeview opens up, moving the rest of my project down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0F76.png)

And when the rest of my project moves down, the scroll bar **just does not scroll down**.
[Scroll Bar stuck and not working on moving it up or down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HOeU.png)
What am I doing wrong here?
I know one solution is to open the treeview widget as a Toplevel() but I want it to be opened within the same page. Please answer my question, thank you!

One more thing: the entire alignment gets messed up when I try to pack that frame which comprises of all my widgets inside the encompasser. The whole project shifts towards the left hand side and aesthetically it does not look nice.

[Showing what happened when I removed the frame called "encompasser"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElE47.png)

Comment: IS there a better way of adding a full screen scrollbar to our projects?

Comment: I think your case would be a lot clearer if your asked them as separate questions.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow so I can ask only a few questions, I have a cooldown time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have created another frame using the same variable name `encompasser`:

```py
encompasser=Frame(my_canvas,bg=mainbg, borderwidth=0)
encompasser.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

The above two lines should be removed.

Second, you should update the `scrollregion` when the internal frame `encompasser` is resized, not `my_canvas`.

Remove the line:

```py
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

and add the below line after creating `encompasser`:

```
encompasser.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))
```

Comment: ```encompasser=Frame(my_canvas,bg=mainbg, borderwidth=0)
encompasser.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)``` when I removed these lines, my project got sliced in half and only half of it is visible, while the other half is blank white. (Editing post to share screenshot)

Comment: After I added the line ```encompasser.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))
```, the window has been restored to its default state where my project is not sliced in half, the scrollbar is visible but is frozen in its tracks

Comment: Change `anchor="n"` to `anchor="nw"` in `my_canvas.create_window(...)`.

Comment: Sorry to say but same problem of the scroll bar not moving whatsoever. Nevermind, I have created it as a Toplevel() window and have submitted the project... Thanks for helping! :)